# Chart for cumulative values

Tags: javascript, charts, cumulative-sum

I am looking for a charting library that renders cumulative values.

For example, I have this list:

- January: 50
- February: 150
- March: 25

I need the chart to plot 50 for January, 200 (50+150) for February, and 225 (50+150+25) for March.

I realize that my example is very simple, but in real life it can become more complicated, involving filtering or grouping. That's why I am hoping to find a library with prebuilt functions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TufteGraph](http://xaviershay.github.com/tufte-graph/), you can easily customized the inputs through a function.